# Break out cost by year and then month by customer by indexing rows

Tags: r

I have a data set

```
dt <- data.table(Customer = c("a", "a", "c"), months = c(24, 12, 37), Date = c("2019-02-23","2019-03-31","2019-10-01"), Cost = c("100","200","370"))
```

I am looking to break out costs by year and repeat the customer (by row number)

```
months_to_year <- function(months){
  if(months%%12==0) y <- rep(12, months %/%  12) else y <- c(rep(12, months %/%  12), months %% 12)
  return(y)
}

dt$years<- dt$months/12
dt$Cost <- as.numeric(dt$Cost)
dt<- dt %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), rn = row_number()) %>% 
  slice(rep(rn, ceiling(months/12)))%>%
  group_by(Customer, rn) %>%
  mutate(months1 = months_to_year(first(months)),
         Date = seq(first(Date), by="1 year", length.out=n()),
         Cost = Cost/months * months1)
```

I get the following output

```
  Customer months Date        Cost years    rn months1
  <chr>     <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
1 a            24 2019-02-23    50  2        1      12
2 a            24 2020-02-23    50  2        1      12
3 a            12 2019-03-31   200  1        2      12
4 c            37 2019-10-01   120  3.08     3      12
5 c            37 2020-10-01   120  3.08     3      12
6 c            37 2021-10-01   120  3.08     3      12
7 c            37 2022-10-01    10  3.08     3       1
```

Now I am looking to further break it down by month

```
dt %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), rn1 = row_number()) %>% 
  slice(rep(rn1, months1))%>%
  group_by(Customer, rn1) %>%
  mutate(New.Date = seq(first(Date), by="1 month", length.out=n()))
```

However, the customer "a" in line 3 gets indexed to rn1=1 & the new start date is 1 month increment from the previous rn=1 index for customer "a". Refer New date column rows 12 and 25...I am looking to get the new date in line 25 to start 2019-03-31.

```
[![dt output][1]][1]
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to upload a picture of the dt output, and the console isn't returning the entire output...if the last bit of code is assigned to a variable and then viewed (eg: View(dt)), then it would be a good reference

Comment: I feel like this would be a lot easier using dataframes and `lubridate`.

Comment: I struggle to understand what you're trying to do, mostly because you don't provide your expected output for the sample data you give. Furthermore, why have a `data.table` but then use `tidyverse` syntax? Why not stay within the `data.table` realm?

Comment: @Maurits Evers Please use this link to view the output....https://drive.google.com/file/d/14g_K8_DKyEZ5qDHIVd0BgUDp1GRChJfp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This might work. I editedd your sample data a bit, so get columns in the right type..

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(Customer = c("a", "a", "c"), months_num = c(24, 12, 37), Date = c("2019-02-23","2019-03-31","2019-10-01"), Cost = c(100,200,370))
#set dates
dt[, Date := as.POSIXct( Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d" ) ]
dt[, EndDate := Date %m+% months( months_num )][]

str(dt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Customer  : chr  "a" "a" "c"
# $ months_num: num  24 12 37
# $ Date      : POSIXct, format: "2019-02-23" "2019-03-31" "2019-10-01"
# $ Cost      : num  100 200 370
# $ EndDate   : POSIXct, format: "2021-02-23" "2020-03-31" "2022-11-01"
```

**code**

Actually a one-liner, but spilt over multipe lines for readablility on SO.

```
#monthly
dt[ , .( Customer = Customer, 
         month = seq(Date, 
                     by = "month", 
                     length.out = months_num ),
         Cost = Cost / months_num ), 
    by = .(id = 1:nrow(dt) )][]
```